# textflow event to know when the text has been displayed

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, textflow

I need to know when the text of the TextFlow has been displayed.

the code runs inside a MovieClip and I have tried the follow events:

textFlow.addEventListener(FlowOperationEvent.FLOW_OPERATION_END, handleEnd); (never happens)
textFlow.addEventListener(UpdateCompleteEvent.COMPOSITION_COMPLETE, handleDone); (when it happen, the text is not displayed)

Its looks like the text is only rendered on the "next" frame, but I can't find an event that notify that the text is been displayed.

I near out of ideas, so if any one have some suggestion please share them :D

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you mixed up the event.
Have you tried.

```
textFlow.addEventListener(FlowOperationEvent.FLOW_OPERATION_COMPLETE, onFlowComplete);
```

Comment: yes, I also tried that one, and the .FLOW_OPERATION_BEGIN as well, and the result is the same.

Comment: @NFRiaCowboy The code you posted shows UpdateCompleteEvent.COMPOSITION_COMPLETE not FlowOperationEvent.FLOW_OPERATION_COMPLETE

Comment: sorry for the late answer, but the result is the same, the event is never fired